# Why do I have to run dhclient on boot?

Tags: debian, dhclient, dist-upgrade

After a top-notch decision to blindly dist-upgrade, I have to run dhclient after every boot.

I understand that I can fix this with a script on startup, but it bothers me that I have no idea what caused this or even how to begin properly tracking it down.

Comment: :) "top-notch decision"... I like that. My experience is the `dist-upgrade` route has many potholes. I had to decide whether it was something I was missing, or was it just really difficult to get it all right. I decided on the latter. Also in my experience, it's quicksand: the more you struggle, the deeper you sink. Conclusion: Life is short, therefore: backup, re-install, restore, move on.

Comment: Nah, if I'm going to give up like that I can just run a script at boot.